# Is there any way to get test name with code coverage in C#?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, console-application, code-coverage

I have generated code coverage file which only tells the lines covered. I am trying to get the names of tests with coverage information. I have tried Microsoft Code Coverage and DotCover but they only provide coverage info. I need this functionality at console app.

Please suggest any solution.

Comment: Can you share how are you generating the coverage result and export it to file? How's current coverage result look like?

Comment: I am simply using Visual Studio Agents 2017                                          Command:             
vstest.console.exe MyTestAssembly.dll /EnableCodeCoverage                    It generates .Coverage file, which i convert into XML format.

Comment: <modules>  
     <function id="129428" token="0x6000819" name="GetNodeAt(type,int)" namespace="abc.xyz" type_name="" block_coverage="66.67" line_coverage="68.75" blocks_covered="12" blocks_not_covered="6" lines_covered="11" lines_partially_covered="0" lines_not_covered="5">
          <ranges>
            <range source_id="18" covered="yes" start_line="95" start_column="3" end_line="95" end_column="4" />
          </ranges>
        </function>
    <source_files>
         <source_file id="18" path="XYZ\Abc.cs">
        </source_file>
  </source_files>
    </module>
  </modules>

Comment: Test name with coverage information... Not sure how test name and coverage are relevant. It won't give you proper coverage for sure. Coverage is calculated for the code being tested, not for the code which is testing. Multiple tests can be executing the same target code so if you are expecting to get target code coverage by test name then surely it will be misleading. Can you tell us why you want the test case name with code coverage information?

Comment: Actually we have thousands of test cases and we are building a dictionary where we will dump every covered method information with its relevant test methods names. whenever we perform change in our covered code, our tool will detect changes in modified method and will run only associated test methods. In this way we can save a lot of time.
My thinking is that coverage %age is calculated by executing test methods, when a test method hits a specific line then a line is considered as covered, why we can't get the name of that test method at that time.